# How to preprocess values passed to CreateView

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I want to preprocess values submitted to a `CreateView` in order to get them validated. For example, a custom int-parser for a string entered in the form.

In my case I want to convert a string entered in a `CreateView` form like "1:54.363" to an integer (with an existing function `parse_laptime`), which is then saved in my model:

```
class Lap(models.Model):
    laptime = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

How can this be accomplished best? I'm new to Django and tried using a custom Form with overwritten `clean` method, but the field fails validation beforehand and is not passed to `clean()`.

Comment: Please show the code you tried.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are on the right track in using the form to validate your data.  However, your input is failing the validation test simply because the input data, formatted as a time value, is not the integer that your model requires.

You should use an unbound field in the form (or an unbound form) that accepts the data as entered - maybe as a character field.  Then, use the clean method for this unbound field to confirm that the data can be converted (based on format and/or value).  The actual conversion should happen in the view logic, perhaps in the form_valid() method.

Answer (score 1):

Laptime is a time and if you expect the user to enter it in the format "1:54.363" the right field to use is [TimeField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/forms/fields/#timefield)

> Validates that the given value is either a datetime.time or string
>   formatted in a particular time format

It seems that you are storing them in the database as microseconds. You would then need to check the form.is_valid() method and do the convertion either using the date time function or split and arithmatic.
.

Comment: From what I understand, TimeField represents the time of day, not an absolute time like a laptime. TimeField is also limited to 24 hours. But when it comes to formatting and storing the time of day, you are right.

Comment: Okay, I just figured there is a DurationField, which is almost what I need. Subclassing DurationField solved my problem in this case, but doesn't really answer the question.